# How copy take place in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

On the link

http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/advanced_numpy/

there is statement ,

there is no way to represent the array c given one stride and the block of memory for a. Therefore, the reshape operation needs to make a copy here.

How this copy works inside numpy ? What is time complexity of that ? 
How numpy gets to know further array can't be represented using same array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two dimensions of an array, with shapes `sh0` and `sh1` and strides `st0` and `st1`, that you want to merge into a single dimension of shape `sh0*sh1`, the condition to be able to do so without a copy is that `st0 == sh1*st1`. Notice that the order the dimensions come up in the shape is relevant, and in a C order array with positive strides, dimension `0` precedes dimension `1`.

There may be situations that require a more subtle analysis, about which stride and shape to multiply to compare to which stride, if you have Fortran order arrays, or negative strides, but the basic premise is still mostly the same.

Comment: how numpy knows further mapping is not possible and now copies data into another array ?